# Apply .value_counts() on DataFrame with lists populated in each cell

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently using a data frame, which has a column of type list (with strings) in each of its cells.
I'm interested in applying `value.counts()` on it as if all the lists would have been concatinated into a single huge list (tried to do that, didn't work very well)

Toy example of the data structure that i have:

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = pd.DataFrame({'listcol':[['a','b','c'],['a','b','c']]})
print df_list
     listcol
0  [a, b, c]
1  [a, b, c]
```

I would like to apply on it `value.counts()` as it would  have, if it was a big concatinated list as following:

```
#desired output:
df=pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','a','b','c'])
df.columns = ['col']
df.col.value_counts() #desired output!
b    2
c    2
a    2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need first create flatten `list` and then apply `Counter`, last create `Series`:

```
from  itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

print (Counter(chain.from_iterable(df_list['listcol'])))
Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 2, 'c': 2}

s = pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df_list['listcol'])))
print (s)
a    2
b    2
c    2
dtype: int64
```

Or create `Series` and use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
#for python 2 omit list
s = pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(df_list['listcol'])))
print (s)
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    b
5    c
dtype: object

print (s.value_counts())
c    2
a    2
b    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, man! exactly what I looked for, could you add some sorting to it ? :)

Comment: `value_counts` sorts by default, for first solution need `s = s.sort_values()`

Comment: or `s = s.sort_values(ascending=False)` ;)